# Python, Pandas: Compare dataframes and keep old, updated and new ones separately

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

Good evening,

let's say I have two dataframes:

**Dataframe 1:**

```
id    |    first_name    |    last_name    |    age    |    personnel_number
1     |    Jane          |    Doe          |    37     |    0045ac
2     |    John          |    Doe          |    35     |    0102ha
3     |    Sarah         |    Smith        |    28     |    1003px
17    |    Michael       |    Mueller      |    61     |    0800pw
```

**Dataframe 2:**

```
id    |    first_name    |    last_name    |    age    |    personnel_number
1     |    Jane          |    Doe          |    37     |    0045ac
2     |    John          |    Doe          |    35     |    0102ha
3     |    Sarah         |    Smith        |    41     |    1003px
4     |    Sam           |    Smith        |    24     |    0017ix
```

I know, that with the following code I'm getting a new dataframe, where the existing rows are getting updated and the new ones are added...

```
df_comp = df2.set_index('personnel_number').combine_first(df1.set_index('personnel_number')).reset_index()
```

...to achieve this:

**Combinded Dataframe:**

```
id    |    first_name    |    last_name    |    age    |    personnel_number
1     |    Jane          |    Doe          |    37     |    0045ac
2     |    John          |    Doe          |    35     |    0102ha
3     |    Sarah         |    Smith        |    41     |    1003px
17    |    Michael       |    Mueller      |    61     |    0800pw
4     |    Sam           |    Smith        |    24     |    0017ix
```

My question: Is there a way to achieve three instead of one combined dataframe with the following data:

- Dataframe with the already existing data that hasn't changed
- Dataframe with rows that got updated
- Dataframe with the new rows

**Notes**

- there is always a column with unique data ('personnel_number' in this example)

Thanks for your help and advice and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try outer merge with indicator and then some conditions followed by a groupby then store in a dictionary:

```
out = df2.merge(df1,how='outer',indicator='group')

c = out.groupby("personnel_number",sort=False).transform('nunique').gt(1).any(1)

out['group'] = (np.select([out['group'].eq("both"),out['group'].ne("both") & c,
                           out['group'].isin(['both','left_only']) & ~c],
                          ['Already_exists','Updated','New']))

d = dict(iter(out.groupby("group")))
```

---

Output:

[image]